# Constant value for WC_TREEVIEW in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, api, winapi

Any one please tell constant value for WC_TREEVIEW? I am creating an application in wpf with Win32 control.
I would like to add the control as TreeView. i used the following code,

```
HWND hwndTree = CreateWindowEx(
WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
WC_TREEVIEW,
0,
WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom,
hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

But i don't know the value of WC_TREEVIEW. Please tell any one.

Answer (score 1):

The macro is defined in the Platform SDK's `<CommCtrl.h>` header as follows:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define WC_TREEVIEWA            "SysTreeView32"
    #define WC_TREEVIEWW            L"SysTreeView32"

    #ifdef UNICODE
        #define  WC_TREEVIEW            WC_TREEVIEWW
    #else
        #define  WC_TREEVIEW            WC_TREEVIEWA
    #endif

#else
    #define WC_TREEVIEW             "SysTreeView"
#endif
```

Depending on your requirements (ANSI or UNICODE; x86 or x64) you have to pick one. If you are targetting 64-bit simply use `"SysTreeView"`. For a 32-bit target platform you have to use `"SysTreeView32"` either as an ANSI or UNICODE string.

The following table lists the string literals for the possible combinations:

```
        |      32-bit      |    64-bit
--------+------------------+--------------
ANSI    | "SysTreeView32"  | "SysTreeView"
--------+------------------+--------------
UNICODE | L"SysTreeView32" | "SysTreeView"
```